# PHP Empty Object in Class

Tags: php

Why is PHP Saying that my object is empty ?

Here is a simple use case.
It keeps returning the following error :

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\AdvancedApp\myApp.php on line 10.

```
class myClass
{
    public $myFunction = "Hello World";
}

$class = new myClass();

echo $class->$myFunction;
```

Comment: no more `$` sign on the property when accessing it, just `echo $class->myFunction;` alone, by the way, that name is misleading

Answer (score 3):

The correct use of property is:

```
echo $class->myFunction;
```

What you did is used **variable variables**, the following will work:

```
$name = "myFunction" ;
echo $class->$name ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `$` sign from `$myClass->$myFunction` so it will be `$myClass->myFunction`, and what's with the variable name. Use something else, like `myValue`...